# Pytorch-GPU what am I forgetting to move over to the GPU?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, gpu

I'm getting this error. What am I leaving out, I feel that I have tired everything.
Also is there not a easy way to just use the GPU and not the CPU I feel like I have tried all those options as well. As in not using .cuda() everywhere

This is one of my first neutral networks so please go easy on me. (most of it is from Class)

```
 RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking arugment for argument target in method wrapper_nll_loss_forward)


import torch.cuda
import numpy as np
import time
from torchvision import datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchsummary import summary

torch.cuda.set_device(0)

def load_data():

    num_workers = 0

    load_data.batch_size = 20

    transform = transforms.ToTensor()


    train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    test_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)


    load_data.train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, 
                                batch_size=load_data.batch_size, num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=True)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, 
                                batch_size=load_data.batch_size, num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=True)



def visualize():

    dataiter = iter(load_data.train_loader)
    visualize.images, labels = dataiter.next()
    visualize.images = visualize.images.numpy()

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 4))
    for idx in np.arange(load_data.batch_size):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2, load_data.batch_size/2, idx+1, xticks=[], yticks=[])
        ax.imshow(np.squeeze(visualize.images[idx]), cmap='gray')
        ax.set_title(str(labels[idx].item()))
    #plt.show()

def fig_values():
    img = np.squeeze(visualize.images[1])

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    width, height = img.shape
    thresh = img.max()/2.5
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            val = round(img[x][y],2) if img[x][y] !=0 else 0
            ax.annotate(str(val), xy=(y,x),
                        horizontalalignment='center',
                        verticalalignment='center',
                        color='white' if img[x][y]<thresh else 'black')
    #plt.show()


load_data()
visualize()
fig_values()

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, gpu = True):
        super(NeuralNet, self ).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28 * 28, 16).cuda()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(16, 10).cuda()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 28 * 28).cuda()
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)).cuda()

        x = self.fc2(x).cuda()

        return x


def training():
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().cuda()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
    n_epochs = 100 

    model.train().cuda()

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        train_loss = 0.0
        for data, target in load_data.train_loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = model(data)
            loss = criterion(output, target)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            train_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)

        train_loss = train_loss/len(load_data.train_loader.dataset)

        print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
            epoch+1, 
            train_loss
            ))


device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

model = NeuralNet().to(device)
summary(model, input_size=(1, 28, 28))
training()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data`, and `target` are not in GPU (considering the removal of repeated `cuda` calls).

You are also doing of unnecessary `cuda()` which is not needed. Simply, see where your data and model are. Take the model to GPU, take the data and label to GPU, finally feed data to the model.

Don't use, `cuda()`, use `to.device()`, it's safer in the long run and easily customizable in multi-gpu setup.

```
import torch.cuda
import numpy as np
import time
from torchvision import datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchsummary import summary

torch.cuda.set_device(0)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

def load_data():

    num_workers = 0

    load_data.batch_size = 20

    transform = transforms.ToTensor()


    train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    test_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)


    load_data.train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, 
                                batch_size=load_data.batch_size, num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=True)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, 
                                batch_size=load_data.batch_size, num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=True)



def visualize():

    dataiter = iter(load_data.train_loader)
    visualize.images, labels = dataiter.next()
    visualize.images = visualize.images.numpy()

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 4))
    for idx in np.arange(load_data.batch_size):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2, load_data.batch_size/2, idx+1, xticks=[], yticks=[])
        ax.imshow(np.squeeze(visualize.images[idx]), cmap='gray')
        ax.set_title(str(labels[idx].item()))
    #plt.show()

def fig_values():
    img = np.squeeze(visualize.images[1])

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    width, height = img.shape
    thresh = img.max()/2.5
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            val = round(img[x][y],2) if img[x][y] !=0 else 0
            ax.annotate(str(val), xy=(y,x),
                        horizontalalignment='center',
                        verticalalignment='center',
                        color='white' if img[x][y]<thresh else 'black')
    #plt.show()


load_data()
visualize()
fig_values()

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, gpu = True):
        super(NeuralNet, self ).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28 * 28, 16)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(16, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 28 * 28)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))

        x = self.fc2(x)

        return x


def training():
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
    n_epochs = 100 

    model.train()

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        train_loss = 0.0
        for data, target in load_data.train_loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            ###################################
            data = data.to(device)
            target = target.to(device)
            ###################################
            output = model(data)
            loss = criterion(output, target)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            train_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)

        train_loss = train_loss/len(load_data.train_loader.dataset)

        print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
            epoch+1, 
            train_loss
            ))




model = NeuralNet().to(device)
summary(model, input_size=(1, 28, 28))
training()
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your `target` variable is not on GPU.

Also, its a bad idea to call `.cuda()` inside `forward()`

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = x.view(-1, 28 * 28).cuda() # BAD
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)).cuda() # BAD
    x = self.fc2(x).cuda() #BAD
    return x
```

Rather, remove all `.cuda()` inside forward and do this is main loop

```
for data, target in load_data.train_loader:
    data = data.cuda()
    target = target.cuda()
```